# How to execute a function in a UIViewController through a SwiftUI Button?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

**In the code below**, I am trying to figure out how to execute the `savePhoto` function with a `SwiftUI` button. This is actually the simplified version of the problem I am trying to solve, but still can't figure this out. The button I created in the `ContentView` is how I would imagine to solve the problem, but because of the SwiftUI structs, I can't seem to find a way around it.

**Here is my SwiftUI view:**

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            AnotherControllerView()
            Button(action: { AnotherControllerView.savePhoto() }){
                Text("Save Photo")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

**And my integrated UIViewController:**

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import UIKit

struct AnotherControllerView : UIViewControllerRepresentable {

    typealias UIViewControllerType = AnotherController

    func makeCoordinator() -> AnotherControllerView.Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<AnotherControllerView>) -> AnotherController {

        return AnotherController()
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: AnotherController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<AnotherControllerView>) {

    }


    class Coordinator : NSObject {
        var parent : AnotherControllerView
        init(_ viewController : AnotherControllerView){
            self.parent = viewController
        }
    }
}

class AnotherController : UIViewController {


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    }

    func savePhoto(){

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Save Photo to Camera Roll", message: "Would you like to save your drawing to the camera roll?", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default, handler: nil))
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Save", style: .default, handler: someHandler))
        self.present(alert, animated: true)
    }

    func someHandler(alert: UIAlertAction!) {
        print("Handler executed")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hello to control the UIViewController we need to create a bind between the View and UIViewControllerRepresentable 
let explain it in code:
first you need to declare a new variable annotated with `@Binding` inside the `AnotherControllerView`

it will be like this :

```
struct AnotherControllerView : UIViewControllerRepresentable {

    @Binding var isShown: Bool
    typealias UIViewControllerType = AnotherController

    func makeCoordinator() -> AnotherControllerView.Coordinator {
        Coordinator()
    }

    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<AnotherControllerView>) -> AnotherController {

        return AnotherController(isShown: $isShown)
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ controller: AnotherController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<AnotherControllerView>) {
        if(self.isShown){
            controller.savePhoto()
        }
    }


    class Coordinator : NSObject {

    }
}
```

so for that in the `updateUIViewController` we implement the logic there

```
class AnotherController : UIViewController {

     @Binding var isShown: Bool

    init(isShown: Binding<Bool>) {
        _isShown = isShown
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)

    }



    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    }

    func savePhoto(){

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Save Photo to Camera Roll", message: "Would you like to save your drawing to the camera roll?", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default, handler: cancelAlert))
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Save", style: .default, handler: someHandler))
        self.present(alert, animated: true)
    }

    func cancelAlert(alert: UIAlertAction!) {
        self.isShown = false
    }

    func someHandler(alert: UIAlertAction!) {
        print("Handler executed")
    }
}
```

and if you're trying to capture an image let me show you how I implemented this:

```
struct CaptureImageView {
    @Binding var isShown: Bool
    @Binding var image: Image?
    var sourceType: UIImagePickerController.SourceType

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(isShown: $isShown, image: $image)
    }
}

extension CaptureImageView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<CaptureImageView>) -> UIImagePickerController {
        let picker = UIImagePickerController()
        picker.delegate = context.coordinator
        picker.sourceType = sourceType
        return picker
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIImagePickerController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<CaptureImageView>) {

    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {
        @Binding var isCoordindatorShown: Bool
        @Binding var imageInCoordinator: Image?

        init(isShown: Binding<Bool>, image: Binding<Image?>) {
            _isCoordindatorShown = isShown
            _imageInCoordinator = image
        }

        func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
            guard let unwrapImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage else {return}
            imageInCoordinator = Image(uiImage: unwrapImage)
            isCoordindatorShown = false
        }

        func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
            isCoordindatorShown = false
        }
    }

}
```

and in the body I just call :

```
CaptureImageView(isShown: $showCaptureImageView, image: $imageCaptured, sourceType: importSourceType)
```

Comment: The designated initialiser for UIViewController is initWithNibName:bundle:. You should be calling that instead. If you don't have a nib, pass in nil for the nibName (bundle is optional too). Then you could construct a custom view in loadView or by adding subviews to self.view in viewDidLoad, same as you used to.

Comment: Thanks so much. I made twerk and was able to achieve what I was after, which is just to save a UIImage within the UIViewController. However, are you not getting the double alert when `savePhoto()` is executed? It seems like it want you to run the alert through SwiftUI.

`2019-12-02 12:54:27.434741-0500 CoordinatorVC[1048:209323] Warning: Attempt to present <UIAlertController: 0x101888400>  on <CoordinatorVC.AnotherController: 0x100c13010> which is already presenting (null)`

Comment: yes you are right I'm getting it twice I I added an alert as you said on the view directly

Comment: So you check if a boolean is set and when it is, call the corresponding function? What happens when `updateUIViewController` is called again via a different state update? The function would erroneously be called again unless you reset the booleans value at the end of the function. _However_ if you reset the boolean at the end of the function then you get stuck in a state modification loop: "Modifying state during view update, this will cause undefined behavior."

Answer (score 1):

If the AnotherControllerView is large and you use it scarcely in the new, you may consider use a simpler workaround.

```swift
struct ContentAnotherControllerView: View {
                
    let anotherControllerView = AnotherControllerView()
                
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            anotherControllerView
            Button(action: { anotherControllerView.savePhoto() }) {
                Text("Save Photo")
            }
        }
    }
}



struct AnotherControllerView : UIViewControllerRepresentable {

    typealias UIViewControllerType = AnotherController
    var savePhotoDelegate: AnotherController? = AnotherController()
    
    func savePhoto(){
        savePhotoDelegate?.savePhoto()
    }
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<AnotherControllerView>) -> AnotherController {
        if let savePhotoDelegate = savePhotoDelegate {
            return savePhotoDelegate
        }
        return AnotherController()
    }
}
```

This approach is just to remind us one view can be reused in some situation. As the UIView bridge is not a pure SwiftUI domain, you can try this way.